# How to create custom types using typing module?

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-typing

I am trying to create a custom type on Python 3.7 typing module. The new type (say `Struct`) should be same as type `tuple`. In Python3.6, I was able to do same by `Typing.GenericMeta` and `typing.TupleMeta`.

With typing module updated in Python3.7, `GenericMeta` and `TupleMeta` do not exist, and the special class that I would like to subclass, is not possible. e.g. `_VariadicGenericAlias`.

What I really want is something similar to:

```
Struct = _VariadicGenericAlias(tuple, (), , inst=False, special=True)
```

and

```
assert _origin(Struct[int, str]) == Struct
```

Note:

```
def _origin(typ: Any) -> Any:
    """Get the original (the bare) typing class.
    Get the unsubscripted version of a type. Supports generic types, Union,
    Callable, and Tuple. Returns None for unsupported types. Examples::
        get_origin(int) == None
        get_origin(ClassVar[int]) == None
        get_origin(Generic) == Generic
        get_origin(Generic[T]) == Generic
        get_origin(Union[T, int]) == Union
        get_origin(List[Tuple[T, T]][int]) == list
    """
    if isinstance(typ, _GenericAlias):
        return typ.__origin__ if typ.__origin__ is not ClassVar else None
    if typ is Generic:
        return Generic
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out solution that worked for me. Made use of "name" param that was somewhere hidden in _GenericAlias:

```
Struct = _VariadicGenericAlias(tuple, (), , inst=False, special=True, name="Struct")
```